# How to get all links from html?

Tags: java, android, hyperlink

In my app I have the WebView which shows html files. So I want to get all links from the displayed file and put them into another activity with listview.

For example:
I have following links in the displayed file:

```
<a href="somelink1.html">SomeLink1</a>
<a href="somelink2.html">Somelink2</a>
```

and I want to show titles of these links in ListView, click on the item will open the appropriate file.

Here is the code of ListView in which I want to show these links:

```
public class ListWithLinks extends Activity 
{
    private ListView lv1;
    private String lv_arr[]

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.list, lv_arr));
        lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) 
            {
                     //my stuff
                }

        }
}
```

So I need to populate the list with titles and assign each element with the appropriate link.

How can I do that? Help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many HTML parsing libraries, like for example [jsoup](http://jsoup.org). You can find very simple and clear example in one of the Cookbook pages [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation).

Hope this helps,
Serhiy.